# Extracting the string after the last / in Google Data Studio (REGEXP problem)

Tags: regex, looker-studio, text-extraction, re2

I'm currently working with Google Data Studio and would like to format Landing Page so it only shows the last part of the string (after the last /). So 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit' becomes 'submit'.

I'm using this query but it's only bringing back NULL. Is there something which I need to tweak? 
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing_page_no_trailing_slash,'[^/]*$')

I've seen a couple of solutions which solve this with lastindexof but this doesn't work in Google Data Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The following [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) captures the characters `a-zA-Z0-9_-` after the last `/`

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing_page_no_trailing_slash,"/([\\w-]+)$")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/a272b2c0-0aa3-4b60-84ab-73f367a27ee0) to demonstrate:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Close, you need to escape the slash your regex should be `[^\/]*$`

Try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/GsYncz/1)

Consider changing the `*` quantifier to `+` if you will always have text after the last slash, it requires more than one character, not just zero; `*` will produce two matches one with your desired text and a zero-length match right at the end of the string.

I would recommend [`\[^\/\]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/FoPsoW/1) as an improvement.